# Inline CSS styling behavior in VueJs

Tags: css, vue.js, inline

I have an <input> in my HTML that can set the background color on a <p> as an inline style. I experimented with two ways of setting the style, and I don't understand one particular behavior: if I type blue, both paragraph become blue. But then if I do backspace, Paragraph 2 stays blue until the input field is empty or has another valid color (ex: backspacing from yellowgreen to yellow), which is weird to me. Paragraph 1 on the other hand has the expected behavior: if the input is not a valid color, it is unstyled.

I guess it has something to do with the way Vue  transforms a "style object" into actual css styles. How does it work? (Just in case: I am completely new to Vue.js)

HTML:

```
<section id="assignment">
  <input type="text" v-model="bgc" />
  <p :style="bgcInlineStyle">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p :style="{backgroundColor: bgc}">Paragraph 2</p>
</section>
```

JS:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      bgc: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    bgcInlineStyle() {
      return `background-color:${this.bgc};`;
    },
  },
});

app.mount("#assignment");
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because computed properties are cached based on their reactive dependencies

Reference: [Computed Property and Caching](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Answer (score 0):

In Paragraph 1, you are binding a string value to the style attribute.

In Paragraph 2, you are binding an object value to the style attribute.

For string values, the browser will parse the style attribute and immediately update the rendering. If an invalid property or invalid property-value is added, CSS will ignore it.

For object values, Vue will dynamically update the style properties using the object key-value pairs. If an invalid value is encountered, it will ignore the property and avoid updating it through JavaScript. This is why the background color stays blue.

Vue handles style objects using JavaScript, for example:

```
document.querySelector("p").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
document.querySelector("p").style.backgroundColor = "blu"; // this will be ignored, it will not 'reset' the value to a blank state
```